# Google Chrome Extension for Auto Append query parameter for specific URLs starts with specific domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a specific requirement to create a chrome extension append a query parameter to any URL that starts with a specific domain. For example, let's say the domain is - company.com and the query parameter is ?id=1121212 then whatever the URL user loads in the web browser with the domain company.com it should append the query parameter. ex - company.com/home/?id=1121212, company.com/about/us/?id=1121212 etc...

Is this possible to do in Google Chrome extensions?